# Use image as a border in C#

Tags: c#, image, border

I am creating a custom application in C# and I need to use a bitmap image instead of the standard windows borders. How can i do this?

Comment: Is this Windows Forms? If so, you can remove a Form's border by setting FormBorderStyle to None and ControlBox to false. Then you can put whatever you want in the client area of the Form.

Comment: How custom is that? WPF? WinForms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with WinForms set

`FormBorderStyle`             to `None`
`BackgroundImage`             to your desired image
`BackgroundImageLayout` to `Stretch`

If you want to repeat a pattern on your boder instead, set

`BackgroundImageLayout` to `Tile`

and hide the center of the image with a panel.